# Java Inheritance Syntax error

Tags: java, inheritance

So i've been trying to run this program, for the most part i don't get any errors but I'm getting a syntax error after String [] hpCharacters and String avenCharacters its probably something that i missed.

```
public class Hw1a {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String[] hpCharacters = ("Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger", "Ronald Weasley", "Voldemort");
        Novel harryPotter = new Novel ("Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", 303, hpCharacters);
        harryPotter.summary();
        System.out.println("\n" + harryPotter.isLong());

        String[] avenCharacters = ("Iron Man", "Captain America", "Black Widow", "The Hulk", "Thor");
        GraphicNovel avengers = new GraphicNovel ("Avengers", "Stan Lee", 50, avenCharacters, "Jack Kirby");
        avengers.listCharacters();
        avengers.summary();

        Article pc = new Article ("The Social Meaning of the Personal Computer", "Bryan Pfaffengerger", 10, "Anthropological Quaterly");
        System.out.println("\n" + pc.isLong());
        pc.summary();

    }

}

class ReadingMaterial {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int numPages;

    public ReadingMaterial(String t, String a, int n){
        this.title = t;
        this.author = a;
        this.numPages = n;
    }

    public boolean isLong(){
        if (numPages > 250){
            return true;
                }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void summary() {
        System.out.println(title + "written by" + author);
    }
}

class Novel extends ReadingMaterial {
    private String[] characters;

    public Novel(String t, String a, int n, String[] c) {
        super (t, a, n);
        characters = c;
    }
    public void listCharacters(){
        for(int i=0; i<characters.length; i++){
            System.out.println(characters[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Article extends ReadingMaterial {
    private String publication;
    public Article (String t, String a, int n, String p){
        super (t, a, n);
        this.publication = p;
    }
    public void summary(){
        super.summary();
        System.out.println(", published in" + publication);
    }
}

class GraphicNovel extends Novel {
    private String illustrator;
    public GraphicNovel(String t, String a, int n, String [] c, String i){
        super (t,a, n, c);
        this.illustrator = i;
    }
    public void summary (){
        System.out.println(", illustrated by" + illustrator);

    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays use `{` and `}`, not `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make a `String[]` like this:

```
 String[] hpCharacters = {"Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger", "Ronald Weasley", "Voldemort"};
```

Notice the curly braces `{}` instead of the parenthesis `()`.

Comment: Thank you! i figured it was something silly like that

Comment: No problem. Good luck to you.